# Is it possible to get the latest GitHub release built from a specific branch?

Tags: powershell, github-api

I have a Powershell script that gets the latest release from a repository using Github API. We would like to create a different version of this script which does not get the latest release, but the most recent one created from master. Is this possible? I took a look at the API page: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release and it seems we can only get latest, or a specific release by ID (which the script would not know), or list releases (but apparently not query by them?)

It may be possible using list releases, if I filter the list through code afterwards... except, that API call returns 404 for me every time I call it (despite having over 400 releases):
https://api.github.com/repos/my-org/my-repo/releases.
Which is strange, because if I try a different repo outside of that org it works (returns an empty array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The releases API call returned 404 because I forgot to specify the access token:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/my-org/my-repo/releases?access_token={token}
```

It doesn't seem possible to do what I am asking through the API, but I was able to do it using PowerShell:

```
$releases_url = "https://api.github.com/repos/$repo/releases"

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$releases = Invoke-RestMethod -uri "$($releases_url)?access_token=$($token)"

# Get most recent release from the list where name starts with 'master'.
$latestMasterBuild = $releases | Where { $_.name.StartsWith("master") } | Select -First 1
```

Since my release names were prefixed with the branch they were created from.

Answer (score 3):

If your releases'names don't have a specific naming pattern, you can use the `target_commitish` field in the response of [List Releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository) :

> Specifies the commitish value that determines where the Git tag is
>   created from. Can be any branch or commit SHA. Unused if the Git tag
>   already exists. Default: the repository's default branch (usually
>   master).

You can check the `target_commitish` value using the following [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) and [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) command :

```bash
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/create-react-app/releases?per_page=100" | \
     jq -r '.[].target_commitish'
```

Given that releases are already sorted by most recent first we just need to filter with `target_commitish` value of master :

```bash
curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/create-react-app/releases?per_page=100" | \
     jq -r '[.[] | select(.target_commitish == "master")][0]'
```